# how to find exact modules of python which are there on my windows machine

Tags: python, installation, module

I work on python. My laptop is going to change to a new laptop.

Is there a command which i can run on my old laptop to see which python modules are installed,
and by which commands have i installed them?

so that I can ran that file on my new laptop to install all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Open a `Powershell` terminal and use `pip` like this pip `freeze > requirements.txt` this will list all your modules inside the file `requirements.txt`, then copy this file to your new computer and then on it run this to install all the previous modules `pip install -r requirements.txt`